# STM32 Project with CMake

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, arm, cross-compiling, stm32

I am trying to create and compile an ARM-based STM32 project using CMake.

**CMakeLsts.txt** is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Enable logging messages
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

# Project name
set(PROJECT_NAME FixtureTACO)
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME} C CXX ASM)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

###################### CHIP CONFIGURATION ##########################
SET(ROOT_PROJ   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(CPU         "cortex-m4")
SET(ARCH_NAME   "arm")
SET(ARCH_VER    "v7e-m")
SET(FAMILY      "stm32f3")
SET(CHIP        "STM32F303xC")
SET(ARCH        "${ARCH_NAME}${ARCH_VER}")
####################################################################

# MCU Config
set(FPU         "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16")
set(FLOAT_ABI   "-mfloat-abi=hard")

# Toolchain path
set(TOOLCHAIN_PATH  "")
set(ARM_LIB         "/usr/lib/arm-none-eabi/lib/${ARCH}")
# Specify C, C++ and ASM compilers
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(AS                  ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-as)
set(AR                  ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(OBJCOPY             ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(OBJDUMP             ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(SIZE                ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-size)
set(GDB                 ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-gdb)
set(SIZE                ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-size)

# Definitions passed at compile time (#defines)
add_definitions(-DFAMILY=${FAMILY})
add_definitions(-DCHIP=${CHIP})
add_definitions(-D${CHIP})
add_definitions(-DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER)
add_definitions(-USE_HAL_DRIVER)
add_definitions(-DHSE_VALUE=8000000)
add_definitions(-DHSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT=100)
add_definitions(-DLSE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT=5000)
add_definitions(-DLSE_VALUE=32768)
add_definitions(-DHSI_VALUE=8000000)
add_definitions(-DLSI_VALUE=40000)
add_definitions(-DDD_VALUE=3300)
add_definitions(-DPREFETCH_ENABLE=1)

# Compilation flags
add_compile_options(-mcpu=${CPU})
add_compile_options(-march=${ARCH})
add_compile_options(-mthumb)
add_compile_options(${FPU})
add_compile_options(${FLOAT_ABI})
add_compile_options(-Og)
add_compile_options(-Wall)
add_compile_options(-fdata-sections)
add_compile_options(-ffunction-sections)
# Only for debugging
add_compile_options(-g -gdwarf-2)


# Linker script path
file(GLOB_RECURSE LINKER_SCRIPT ${ROOT_PROJ}/platforms/${FAMILY}/Linker/*.ld)

# Variables initialized first time
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "-std=gnu99")

################################## Source code ###############################################################
# Retrieve all sources # "platforms/${FAMILY}/Startup/*.s"
file(GLOB SOURCES  "platforms/${FAMILY}/Startup/*.s" "src/*.cpp" "src/*.c" "platforms/${FAMILY}/Hal/src/*.c" "platforms/${FAMILY}/Device/*.c")
#Retrieve all locations of headers
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "includes/*.h"  "src/*.h" "platforms/${FAMILY}*.h")
set (INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach (_headerFile ${HEADERS})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES INCLUDE_DIRS)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${ARM_LIB})
################################## Source code END ###########################################################

set(EXE_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}_${CHIP}")
add_executable(${EXE_NAME}.elf ${SOURCES} ${LINKER_SCRIPT})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-mcpu=${CPU} -mthumb ${FPU} ${FLOAT_ABI} --specs=nano.specs -T${LINKER_SCRIPT} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections")

# Libs and external dependencies
target_link_libraries(${EXE_NAME}.elf -lc -lm -lnosys)

# Outputs
set(ELF_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXE_NAME}.elf)
set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXE_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXE_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET "${EXE_NAME}.elf" POST_BUILD
        # Build .hex and .bin files
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Obinary ${ELF_FILE} ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Oihex  ${ELF_FILE} ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMENT "Building ${PROJECT_NAME}.bin and ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex"

        # Copy files to a custom build directory
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${ELF_FILE} "${ROOT_PROJ}/builds/${CHIP}/${EXE_NAME}.elf"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${HEX_FILE} "${ROOT_PROJ}/builds/${CHIP}/${EXE_NAME}.hex"
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${BIN_FILE} "${ROOT_PROJ}/builds/${CHIP}/${EXE_NAME}.bin"

        # Display sizes
        COMMAND ${SIZE} --format=berkeley ${EXE_NAME}.elf ${EXE_NAME}.hex
        COMMENT "Invoking: Cross ARM GNU Print Size"
        )

add_custom_target(UPLOAD
        ${GDB} -iex "target remote tcp:127.0.0.1:3333"
        -iex "monitor program ${EXE_NAME}.elf"
        -iex "monitor reset init"
        -iex "disconnect" -iex "quit ")
```

When I try to compile I am getting the following errors:

```
[ 82%] Building C object CMakeFiles/FixtureTACO_STM32F303xC.elf.dir/platforms/stm32f3/Hal/src/stm32f3xx_ll_utils.c.obj
[ 86%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/FixtureTACO_STM32F303xC.elf.dir/platforms/stm32f3/Startup/startup_stm32f303xc.s.obj
cc: warning: ‘-mcpu=’ is deprecated; use ‘-mtune=’ or ‘-march=’ instead
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’; did you mean ‘-mtbm’?
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16’
cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=hard’
```

The error occurs ONLY when an assembly file (startup.s in this case) is present in source files and when FPU and FLOAR_ABI flags are present. As you can see, error occurs when `startup_stm32f303xc.s` is compiled.

I suspect that I am adding those flags in the wrong place but I have no clue where to add them in order to get it works.

Later edit: I already have installed arm 7 compiler on my ubuntu system. I can use it without specifying any path as it is already present in environment variables. I can compile without problems ARM code (from Makefiles) for other targets on machine. My problem is with cmake.

Comment: My guess is that you need to use generator expressions and the $<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:lang> to only add C options to the C compiler and ASM options to the ASM compiler.  In effect you are adding the options to the compiler for both languages and that is what breaks when compiling the ASM file.

Comment: @Fred I think this is exactly my problem. Can you give me some more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I finally managed to figure it out!

I had to replace

```
set(AS ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-as)
```

with

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  ${TOOLCHAIN_PATH}arm-none-eabi-gcc)
```

It is not a mistake, it is gcc compiler. You can also append these flags:  `-x assembler-with-cpp`.

CMake didn't know about my custom ASM compiler so it was using default system ASM compiler unless I force it by writing `CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER`. Now the project is being build and works fine on microcontroller.

The other answers were ok, but had half of the solution. Only ASM filese were compiled with wrong compiler.

Answer (score 4):

In your line `set(TOOLCHAIN_PATH  "")` you must add a path to compiler. First go to get your free [GCC ARM ToolChain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads). Download for your OS. and then just copy to your favorite location. If you using Linux you can use my path configurations:
1.) Copy gcc arm compirel to /opt/ directory:

```
sudo tar xjfv ~/Downloads/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update-linux.tar.bz2 -C /opt/
```

For more "sexy" path you can do symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update/  /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

After that go to your CMakeLists.txt and rewrite your set command to:

```
set(TOOLCHAIN_PATH  "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin")
```

But there is better solution to build your project for STM32, but with already done [stm32-cmake](https://github.com/ObKo/stm32-cmake) template project, specifically made for STM32 family. It is mush easier done with something working. You will also need two prerequisites STM32CubeMX installed and again GCC ARM ToolChain. If you want to know how to use this template just DM me and I will you give a quick guidance.

Comment: You don't "install" toolchain, you just copy files to one directory. If you already have toolchian files, add path in your code add `set(TOOLCHAIN_PATH   "path/to/your/toolchain/bin")`

Comment: I was just checking stm32-cmake, and it bugs me that CMSIS is mandatory for any project. I want to use plain HAL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to compile code for ARM using x86 compiler. It will not work. You need to download the ARM toolchain and use the correct compiler.

-mcpu is depreciated in the x86 branch, but is not in the ARM branch

another options just not exist in the x86 compiler.

Comment: Yes! This was the problem. Only ASM compiler was omitted, the rest were fine.

Comment: @caffeine great. But the message was actually obvious.